# Conditional crontab entry

Tags: shell, cron

I have a crontab entry that executes a script and stores the output in a file say currenthash.log as an MD5 hash.

But I'm unable to achieve a requirement where I need to create a new file say changedhash.log if the MD5 checksum changes. Is this something I can do in cronjob or in the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

`cron` has no logic regarding how the task is ran.

It just spawn command at the moment you specified.

For that kind of intelligence, you have to implement it in your script.

Another way to manage that could also be using `logrotate` (rotate log files upon some conditions) or [`incron`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) (`cron`-like service where triggers are [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) events instead of time).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the old hash somewhere, then compare it to the new one. Something in this direction:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=/path/to/file
hashfile=/path/to/stored/hash
newhash=$(md5sum "$file")
oldhash=$(cat "$hashfile")
if [ "$newhash" != "$oldhash" ]; then
    echo it changed...
fi
echo "$newhash" > "$hashfile"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to figure out where do I implement this logic. My existing script does something like this `listuser=$(awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} $3 >= 1000 && $3<=65534 {print $1,$6}' /etc/passwd)
echo -e "$listuser" | md5sum` and in the cronjob i'm storing the output to /var/log/userhash.log